# If condition issue (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, complex-numbers

I have an issue with a piece of code in which I have an `if` statement that checks the diagonal elements of a complex array, and if they are (1,0) (meaning the real part is 1 and the imaginary part is 0) or very close to it then proceed; otherwise stop. But for some reason the operation always returns 0 although the elements are (0.999999, 0.000000), (1.000001, 0.000000), etc.

Here's the code I have:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
    if ((real(c[i][i][1]) < (1/100000)+1) && (imag(c[i][i][1]) < 1/100000) && (real(c[i][i][1]) > (-1/100000+1) && (imag(c[i][i][1]) > -1/100000)){
        cout<<"Operation continues...";
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're in over your head. Start with something simple. For example, work out the value of `1/100000` first and see if it is what you think it is.

Comment: 10/100000
This will give the value 0 as it is an integer division.
You might want 10.0/100000

Comment: Refactor it before asking for help please.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even cross my mind that it was integer division.

Comment: Long sequences of zeros are difficult to read and prone to error. I would consider using `1e-5`. And wrapping the comparison in a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This integer division yields 0 because the magnitude of the denominator is greater than that of the numerator:

```
1/100000
```

You need to use at least one floating point number here. For example

```
1.0/100000
```

Answer (score 0):

`1 / 100000 == 0` as it is integer division:
you may write `0.00001` or `1. /100000.`

BTW, you may write your loop:

```
constexpr double thresold = 0.00001;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (std::abs(real(c[i][i][1]) - 1.) < thresold
        && std::abs(imag(c[i][i][1]) - 1.) < thresold) {
        cout << "Operation continues...";
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just simply check if `std::cabs(c[i][i][1] - 1)<threshold`.